# leveling up PHP algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I want some algorithm to make a PHP level up system I already made a system to level up people but what if people gained a huge amount of exp so they need to level up multiple times example of my code:

`if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['amount'])) {
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $user = $_POST['id'];
        $exp;$etnl;$newExp;$level;`

```
    `//select exp and etnl from DB 
    $result = DB::getInstance() ->query("SELECT exp,etnl,level FROM exp WHERE id = $user");
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $result->fetch();
    $exp = $row['exp'];
    $etnl = $row['etnl'];
    $level =  $row['level']
    //c where to level up user or to add exp to his ep bar
    if($amount + $exp > $etnl) {
        $etnl = $etnl * 2;
        $leftOvers = ($amount + $exp) - $etnl;
        $newExp = $leftOvers;
        $level = $level + 1;`


    $result = DB::getInstance()->prepare("UPDATE exp SET exp=?,level=?,etnl=? WHERE id=?");
    $result->execute(array($amount,$level,$etnl,$user));
    } else {
        $result = DB::getInstance()->prepare("UPDATE exp SET exp=? WHERE id=?");
        $result->execute(array($amount,$user));

    }
}`
```

`
        but this system fails if the exp could level up a person 2 times any help or any new code? BTW etnl stands for exp till next level thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to manually type out a level table like the other answer suggets you can also try doing your process with a recursive function:

```
$current_exp = 0;
$current_level = 1;
$to_next_level = 1000;

function did_level( $amount = 0 ) {
    global $current_exp;
    global $curent_level;
    global $to_next_level;

    $tmp_amount = $amount + $current_exp;
    $tmp_amount_remainder = $tmp_amount - $to_next_level;

    if ($tmp_amount >= $to_next_level) {

        $current_level++;
        $to_next_level *= 2;
        $current_exp = $tmp_amount;

        if ($tmp_amount_remainder > 0) {
            // Level us up again.
            did_level( $tmp_amount_remainder );
        } else {
            // Store the new level, to next level, and current exp
        }

    } else {
        // Store the new exp amount
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a table of levels which is basically a list of [exp, level] pairs. For example,

```
$level_list = [
    ['exp' => 0, 'level' => 1],
    ['exp' => 100, 'level' => 2],
    ['exp' => 1000, 'level' => 3],
    // etc.
];
```

Then, you iterate the table starting from the end:

```
$i = count($level_list);

while($i > 0) {
    $i--;
    if ($user_exp >= $level_list[i]['exp']) {
        // this is the level we need
        break;
    }
}

$target_level = $level_list[$i]['level'];
$target_exp = $level_list[$i]['exp'];
```